# How can Community User review a edit and approve

Tags: discussion, community-user

See the screen shot below. It shows that "**Community User**" has reviewed and approved the edit I proposed.
[image]

---

From the below network profile of the "**Community User**" I understand that it is not a person really. How can it say the difference between a good and trivial edit.
[image]

Comment: I suspect this it due to the user having enough rep to edit a post without needing approval, so the approval is automatically done by the Community user.

Comment: So if the user edits were incorrect (say by some misunderstanding or an unacceptable typo) then it is possible that Community might approve it - correct?

Comment: Meta dupe: [Improved edit suggestions approved by Community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80518)

Comment: [Direct link to the review task.](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/505461) I used Improve Edit to remove the `sorry about the formatting. first post :)` cruft.

Answer (score 4):

#### It shows that "Community User" has reviewed and approved the edit I proposed.

When a reviewer (2k+) **improves** a **suggested edit** then it is marked as reviewed and approved by community.

In your example Ben N chose "Improve Edit" during the review.

[image]

---

#### Why Community in this case?

> This is by design. I wanted a simple way to track all the edits that are approved through "improve", it is still easy to track who caused it, cause they are the editors of the revision directly after it.

Source [Improved edit suggestions approved by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80550/267099)

Answer (score 1):

One of the privileges you receive at 2000 rep is the ability to edit other users posts *without* any approval stage. Any user with 2000+ rep can amend any other users post immediately.

Should this occur, the system still expects an approval step, which in this instance will be performed by the user @Community.

For more information, see [here](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: This is a strange structure.  A 2K user can directly edit, but the review queue requires multiple approvals.  Improving an edit is immediately approved, but it's not immediately approved if the 2K user just looks at it and decides it doesn't need further improvement.  It seems like using the Community to do the approval was some kind of workaround to implement this convoluted rule.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, I've always been confused why I can't directly approve an edit. If I made it myself (And I believe if I choose to *improve* the edit) it'll go through instantly. Perhaps it makes sense as to prevent a quick glance over it and approving it, where you might miss something a person added incorrectly as you didn't do it yourself?

Comment: Yeah.  That's our story and we're sticking to it.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 It's not a bug, but a feature... ;)

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. Anyway this is the meta dup: [Improved edit suggestions approved by Community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80518)

Comment: When a reviewer (2k+) **improves** a **suggested edit** then it is marked as reviewed and approved by community. "This is by design.

I wanted a simple way to track all the edits that are approved through "improve", it is still easy to track who caused it, cause they are the editors of the revision directly after it. "